# Laravel Best Practice of working with multiple database

Tags: laravel, database

in web application, i have multiple connection to some databases. if i have access list to the database, then what is good method of accessing it, is by **cookie**, **header**, or include information in every http **request**?

thank you

i prepared access list, i want to know good practice to access selected database

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.